How can I set print dimensions to a specific size in inches?
I need to print the contents of a div in the dimensions of a 3x5 index card on letter sized paper (according to a conversion site  - 3" = 288px and 5" = 480px). When using the following CSS, it targets the appropriate DIV but the (print preview displayed and actual printed) size is much smaller than the specified 3x5 (or 288px x 480px).
@media print {
    @page {
        size: letter;
    }

    body {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #section-to-print {
        visibility: visible;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 288px; /* I've also tried width: 3in; */
        height: 480px; /* I've also tried width: 5in; */
    }
 }

Although I want this printed on letter sized paper, I have also tried the @page size setting to be size: 3in 5in; and size: 288px 480px; but these do not work either - these produce the same results as size: letter;, size: letter portrait;, and size: letter landscape;.
Any assistance that can be provided would be greatly appreciated and thanks for your time. Take care and have a good day.

In case it is requested, here's a watered-down version of my HTML (Razor Page) and its corresponding CSS:
HTML (Razor Page):
@page
@model ExampleProject.Pages.IndexCardModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index Card Print-Out";
    ViewData["ContentBGColor"] = "#FFF";
}


<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>INDEX CARD EXAMPLE</title>

    <link href="~/css/indexcard.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>

    <div class="indexcard-config-3x5-portrait" id="section-to-print">

        <h3 class="indexcard-title">HEADER</h3>

        <div class="ic-table">
            <label>Form Here</label>
        </div>

        <div class="ic-table">
            <label>Table Here</label>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            <label class="footer">&#x2610; Notes on back &#x2192;</label>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>

CSS:
:root {
    --background-color: #FFF;
    --font-color: #000;
    --font-type: Calibri;
    --font-size: .75rem;
}

label {
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-top: .5rem;
    font-size: var(--font-size);
    align-self: end;
}

h3 {
    justify-self: center;
    grid-area: header;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: var(--font-color);
    color: var(--background-color);
    padding: .25rem 0;
    letter-spacing: .65rem;
    font-size: calc(var(--font-size)+.5rem);
}

.indexcard-config-3x5-portrait {
    width: 288px;
    height: 480px;
    padding: .25rem;
    border: 1px solid var(--font-color);
    background-color: var(--background-color);
}

.ic-table {
    margin: .5rem;
    width: 2.75in;
    height: 2in;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffec86;
    color: #00F;
}

.footer {
    float: right;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 0 .5rem 0 0;
}


@media print {
    @page {
        size: letter;
    }

    body {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #section-to-print {
        visibility: visible;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 288px; /* I've also tried width: 3in; */
        height: 480px; /* I've also tried width: 5in; */
    }
 }


Have you tried setting the width and height of #section-to-print using inches instead of pixels?

Indeed, inches, cm or points would be better than px - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units

@Sean - thanks for the reply (and you too Paulie_D) but I have tried setting the width and height to something other than pixels (such as inches) and it still prints the same as it did in pixels.

I've finally figure out my issue. The organization uses a browser based security solution that is applying additional CSS when printing and is the root cause of my issues.
Thanks to anyone that reviewed my post, looked in to this issue, and/or replied.
Take care and have a good day.
